# Javascript number placing and how to , 4 = 0.04, 14 = 0.14, 100 = 1.00

Tags: javascript, html, math, numbers

I am trying to write a custom calculator but I am having trouble trying to work out a figure, I want to be able to add decimal points before the number which has been in puted.

For example if the user puts in 4 I want the value in the string to look like this 0.04 and so on 14 = 0.14, 100 = 1.00.

I tried using the inbuilt function
    var num = 4;
    fig = num.toFixed(2);

But that doesn't work, the only way I can think to do it is with if(val.length >2){ do something; } which would be a long way to do this.
Has any body got any ideas for this?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: `var num = 4; fig = num / 100;`

Comment: that works 4 / 100 but I would like the starting number to be 1.00 (instead of 0.01) and then if the num = 4 the total would be 1.04 if the num = 100 the total would be 2.00 if the num = 101 the total would be 2.01 etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [4, 14, 100].map(function(n) { return (n / 100).toFixed(2) })
["0.04", "0.14", "1.00"]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var num = 4; var fig = num * 0.01;
```

Comment: that sort of works but if I do 200 * 0.01 I get loads of numbers and if I do 100 * 0.01

Ideally I would like the starting number to be 1.00 and then if the num = 4 the total would be 1.04 if the num = 100 the total would be 2.00 if the num = 101 the total would be 2.01 etc..

Thanks

Comment: If you want to start with 1.00, you can simply add 1.00. `var fig = num * 0.01 + 1.00;`