# Javascript number placing and how to , 4 = 1.04, 14 = 1.14, 100 = 2.00

Tags: javascript, html, math, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript number placing and how to , 4 = 0.04, 14 = 0.14, 100 = 1.00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377918/javascript-number-placing-and-how-to-4-0-04-14-0-14-100-1-00)

I am trying to write a custom calculator but I am having trouble trying to work out a figure, I want to be able to add decimal points before the number which has been inputed.

For example if the user puts in 4 I want the value in the string to look like this 1.04 and so on 14 = 1.14, 100 = 2.00.

I tried using the inbuilt function
var num = 4; fig = num.toFixed(2);

But that doesn't work, the only way I can think to do it is with if(val.length >2){ do something; } which would be a long way to do this. Has any body got any ideas for this?

Comment: I don't see a pattern... could you elaborate a bit more on what you're hoping to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to your previous question: [Javascript number placing and how to , 4 = 0.04, 14 = 0.14, 100 = 1.00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377918/javascript-number-placing-and-how-to-4-0-04-14-0-14-100-1-00)

Let's say your user enters a figure which you assign to variable `num`. The result is given by

```
var result = 1 + (num / 100)
```

You could also just add 1 to the result given by any of the answers to your previous question.